# React-Native-webrtc black remote stream

Tags: webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I added video call to my react native app using react-native-webrtc, everything is working fine two devices are connected on the same network but always get a black remote stream on both devices when connected to different networks. I read somewhere that i need a sturn server instead of google sturn server. I deployed a coturn server but still no avail. I though there was a mistake with my coturn server deployment then signup on https://metered.ca and got a turn server but still the same problem. when i console log remote stream in both cases I see remote stream but their only difference is when on different network the property _muted is "true". see screenshots below.
[image: On Thesame network]

[image: On Different Network]

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the perfect stun/turn.. for the peerconnection if you see the iceConnectionFailed log